# How to pass a list in mongo db query

Tags: arrays, json, r, mongodb

This works when I am dynamically querying by just one particular value of col but incase my col is an array eg:  c("red","blue"), it is failing.

## Working for single value

```
col<-"red"
pipe1 <- paste("{\"$match\":{\"color\":\"",col,"\"}}", sep = "")    
query1 <-   list(    
mongo.bson.from.JSON(pipe1),   
mongo.bson.from.JSON('     
                       {
                       "$project" : {   
                       "_id" : 0,   
                       "Email":"$email",  
                       "color":"$color" }    
                       }'))
```

Any solutions? Using this to convert Json to dataframe in R

Answer (score 0):

If `col` is an array, like you say, then the string it produces wouldn't be valid JSON.  I think it would be something like:

```
{"$match":{"color": "red", "blue" }}
```

When what you need is:

```
{"$match":{"color": ["red", "blue"] }}
```